# Validate Unix Timestamp using BASH

Tags: bash, awk, timestamps

My google-fu has failed me so I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction. I'm in the middle of doing some data validation efforts and I suspect the system is recording some invalid dates in the unix epoch format (seconds since the epoch). Is there an easy way in bash, given data that looks like `1357853083` (seconds since the unix epoch) to ascertain if it's a valid unix timestamp or not? Ideally I'm looking for timestamps that cannot be converted to a human readable date as well as timestamps that might render to a future date that's greater than the current date.

I've compiled this monstrosity which converts things into a human readable date, but I can't figure out how to make it find invalid dates.

```
$ grep "delimiter" * | grep -v "delimiter2" | awk -F"," '{print $2}' | awk -F":" '{print $2}' | awk -F"*" '{print $1}' | awk '{printf("%s", strftime("%Y.%m.%d ",$1)); printf("%s", strftime("%H:%M:%S \n",$1))}' | sort -V
```

Comment: This might help give you some ideas: http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/31944-simple-date-time-calulation-bash.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like you want to do two tests.

1. Check for a valid epoch time number which would be from -2147483648 to 2147483647 or +-9.22337203685478E18 depending on whether your system uses 32 or 64 bits for time.
2. You want to check for a number that is less than today's date.

So combining the two tests you are looking for numbers in the range -2147483648 to today's date in epoch time.  The below code should do what you want, although I would raise the lower limit to a reasonable epoch time date such as the date when the computer was installed or your OS compiled.  I arbitrarily set the lower limit to 0 seconds or 1/1/1970.

```
#$i stores the value being tested
#returns failed if it fails validation, otherwise it returns passed
if [ $i -le 0 -o $i -gt `date +%s` ]; then echo "failed"; else echo "passed"; fi;
```